# Can Yonex Accublade boots be used with normal bindings without any damage?

Tags: boots, snowboarding

I've been snowboarding for a few years now and decided to get some secondhand gear as a first step to having my own stuff instead of using rentals. I managed to find a pair of Yonex boots in seemingly good condition that fit my (28-28.5 cm) feet like a glove, and bought them without much thought since boots my size are a bit rare in second-hand stores. It turns out that these are step-in (?) boots meant to be used with matching bindings.

The bottom side looks like these pics from [this listing in an online store](https://www.bloodcomment.top/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=22245) for a different Yonex Accublade model:

[image]
[image]

I'll still be using rental boards until I find a suitable one. I *think* these boots could fit in normal bindings, but I don't want to risk damaging rental stuff. Googling around, everything about Yonex Accublade seems to be in Japanese, so it's hard to find anything related to people using it normal bindings.

Can these boots be used with normal bindings without damaging the board or bindings?

Pictures of the actual boot:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Yonex's step-in bindings in particular, but in terms of damaging rental bindings the only issue would be how flat the bottom is. It seems to have a round curved bar in the left photo. Does that bar extend below the standing base of the boot? If so the pressure on the binding will be concentrated in the one place and can ruin the bindings. If the amount it extends below the boot is minimal (say a couple millimeters) then the foam of the bindings will be able to adapt enough to protect the bindings.

Comment: Thank you! I've added pictures that might clarify more - best I can tell the curved bar is a few mm above the base, and doesn't touch the floor when kept on a flat surface.

Comment: From the added images it is clear the boot will not damage general rental bindings. Enjoy your new boots!

Answer (score 1):

I am very familiar with these boots, they do perform well but they are also about  3.2-3.5 pounds per boot compared to say a Thirty Two tm-2 which are usually 2lbs or  just over per boot.  So you are kind of carrying around all the weight for the accublade step in system and not getting any advantage.   You can search up a "Japanese shopper" who can buy you some used accublade step in bindings from Rakuten (like Japan's eBay) to go with it. I have done this twice, it's maybe $50, but with shipping from Japan it gets a little pricey, like 70 to ship.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, they do seem a bit heavy. I'll try getting a used pair of bindings, but in the meantime it seems it is safe for use with normal bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Bought these a couple of years ago in Japan. They work good with the pro bindings. And the boots also work with normal bindings.

Boots are a little heavy but so good and comfortable